# Php PDO UTF encoding issue even after charset UTF-8

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, utf-8

I am facing some issue with PDP MySQL, I am trying store records in multiple languages, I set charset as UTF8 for all(PHP,MYSQL,PDO), still I am facing issue, the records updating as like below

Steps I followed:

- Set UTF for MySQL DB
- Set UTF8 for MySQL table
- Set UTF8 for PDO (PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'utf8'")
- SET UFT8 for PHP output

But still facing the issue, how ever I can insert/update in phpmyadmin manually without any issue.

Please help me to resolve this.

Thanks,
Ashok

[image: Issue]

[image: DB Collation]
[image: Table Collation]

Comment: Make sure that all your PHP-files are saved as UTF8 w/o BOM and that your HTML (meta fields) and that you are sending Content Type and charset headers using PHP. _Everything_ throughout your code must be set as UTF8 or you can end up with issues like this.

Comment: See Mojibake in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored